# meaning of right off in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> You're pulling the varnish **right off** the walnut.

I guess right off means from. Is it right? Or what does that mean, please?

You're pulling the varnish **from** the walnut?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment left by @whitecap points to the phrasal verb in this sentence (namely, *pull off*).

Eliminate the word *right*, and we have:

> You're pulling the varnish off the walnut.

The word *right* in this context means "directly" or "straight from":

> You're pulling the varnish directly off the walnut.
>
> You're pulling the varnish straight off the walnut.

The word *right* has [several](http://wordnik.com/words/right) usages and meanings, so it is tricky to link this to a dictionary definition. However, here is one I think is pretty close:

> right (*adv.*) exactly; just: *The accident happened right over there*.